# Conventions for naming functions that represent scalar and vector fields in different coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, manifolds, vector-analysis, coordinate-systems

I am looking for some sensible convention for naming functions that represent scalar and vector fields in different coordinates systems.

Currently I am saying something like this:

> Let $f$ be the scalar field in the plane given by the function $g(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$ in the Cartesian coordinates. Then in the polar coordinates the field $f$ is given by the function $h(r,\theta) = r^2$.

I would have much appreciated not having to invent arbitrary names for representations in different coordinate systems of a field named "$f$".

Have differential geometers or vector analysts invented anything?

Comment: Wouldn't parametrization suffice?

Comment: We will just call it $f(x, y)$, $f(r, \theta)$, if no confusion arise.

Comment: "If $f(x, y) = x^2+y^2$, and if $P$ is the polar coordinates mapping, then $(f\circ P)(r,\theta)=r^2$." To me, that seems both simpler and more literally correct.

Comment: @ArcticChar, i do not see how no confusion can arise in this case. What is $f(1,2)$ or $f(s,t)$ or $f(y,x)$ then? What is $f$? Have you seen something similar in any respectable text?